# SQL Server parameter issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, input

Maybe this is not even a question.. but I have a question which I have a feud with my clients...

I have a SQL Server job which has only one step..

The step is:

```
EXEC dbo.MyProc 7
```

while the procedure `dbo.MyProc` is defined as:

```
create dbo.MyProc
   (@Param INT = 30)
as 
begin
    some delete statements here taking @Param as the condition in where clause...
end
```

My questions is about what parameter will the the job work upon.. will it be 7 or will it be 30?

My guess is since 30 is hardcoded in the procedure, the job will run via 30.

I know this question should not have been asked, but I am unable to visualise this..

Pointers and help would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: sure Mr. Marc...will do so..i had written for MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server syntax.  The correct syntax is:

```
create dbo.MyProc (
    @Param int = 30;
)
. . .
```

The `30` is a default value, used when no other value is passed in.  So, for your question, the value "7" is actually what gets passed in.

Comment: Ohh I see...yeah the syntax was @Param int=30;...I missed to write int in my question...so every single time 7 will be passed..right??

Comment: @Anurag . .  Yes, the default is only used when the parameter value is not assigned when you call it.  It makes the parameter a default parameter.